# Handling multiple Postgresql Instances on same port between Local & Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have an issue where my docker container is delivering an error message, `database_1  | 2021-05-03 23:33:49.552 UTC [33] FATAL:  role "myname" does not exist`, for the postgres container I am running and I'm under the impression that it is possibly tied to the fact that its running on the same port as my postgres instance that runs locally on my computer as a background service. Not completely certain, but it seems strange as the role (or I assume username) is present when I connect to a database with my local instance running. Is there something that I can do to further debug? When I run a local node server for the application the credentials work without any issue.

**Here is my `docker-compose.yml` setup:**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:alpine
    database:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
        volumes:
            - nextjs_auth_template:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
    app:
        image: nextjs-auth-boilerplate
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - database
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment: 
            - REDIS_HOST=redis
            - DB_HOSTNAME=database
volumes:
    nextjs_auth_template:
```

**Here is my `.env` file:**

```
DB_USERNAME=myname
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_DATABASE=nextjs_auth_template
DB_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
DB_URL=postgresql://myname@127.0.0.1/nextjs_auth_template
```

Comment: Pretty sure its not a port usage problem, most likely you are running a script that is trying to run under "myname" before it has been created by some other script

Answer (score 0):

If you are running both database instances on the same port and the same host, the problem must be that there is something that tries to connect as that user. If you are running the instance where the user exists, everything works. If you are running the other instance, you'll receive the error.

You'll have to figure out from where the client connects. For that, add `%h` to `log_line_prefix` to get the client IP address logged (change the parameter in the `postgresql.conf` file and reload the server). If you get no IP address in the log, that means that the connection is from your local computer.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz! Do you mind walking me through where I would run the `log_line_prefix` you mentioned? Is this something I would adjust through `psql` or just my terminal?

Comment: I have added quick instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I actually found it to be easier to test by changing the port so there aren't other instances and it looks like the issue was due to the name not being present when the Postgres Docker container is created. My assumption is that I will have to write a command to create that user if I want to connect to it prior to the node server launching